# Implementing Stack and Queue with O(1/B)

Tags: data-structures, stack, queue

This is an exercise from [this](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~mehlhorn/ftp/Mehlhorn-Sanders-Toolbox.pdf) text book (page 77):

> **Exercise 48 (External memory stacks and queues).** Design a stack data structure that needs O(1/B) I/Os per operation in the I/O model
>   from Section 2.2. It suffices to keep two blocks in internal memory.
>   What can happen in a naive implementation with only one block in
>   memory? Adapt your data structure to implement FIFOs, again using two
>   blocks of internal buffer memory. Implement deques using four buffer
>   blocks.

I don't want the code. Can anyone explain me what the question needs, and how can i do operations in O(1/B)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need to tell us what `B` is.

Comment: @Dukeling the question is Exercise 48 in page 77. I believe B is number of blocks. correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the book goes, quoting Section 2.2 on page 27:

> **External Memory:** <...> There are special I/O operations that transfer B consecutive words between slow and fast memory. For
>   example, the external memory could be a hard disk, M would then be the
>   main memory size and B would be a block size that is a good compromise
>   between low latency and high bandwidth. On current technology, M = 1
>   GByte and B = 1 MByte are realistic values. One I/O step would then be
>   around 10ms which is 107 clock cycles of a 1GHz machine. With another
>   setting of the parameters M and B, we could model the smaller access
>   time difference between a hardware cache and main memory.

So, doing things in O(1/B) most likely means, in other words, using a constant number of these I/O operations for each B stack/queue operations.